# Making list from dictionary, but failing with larger value list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary into a list that will be used to create a PySpark dataframe.  I thought I had prototyped it, but then when I tried with a larger (more values in the values list) dictionary, it gave me a puzzling result.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong, or perhaps offer an alternative way to get the result I want?

My dictionary is of the form:

`{key1:[val1, val2, val3], key2:[val4, val5, val6]}`

I'm using a function to turn my dictionary into a list, so given the above I'd like to produce:

`[[key1,val1,val2,val3],[key2,val4,val5,val6]]`

This is my function, with an example of it working correctly:

```
def make_data_list(dict_in):
    # convert dict to list
    input_list = list(dict_in)
    final_list = []
    for tr in input_list:
        data_list = [tr[0]]
        for v in tr[1]:
             data_list.append(v)
    final_list.append(data_list)

return final_list

example_dt = {"10065":[1,2,3,4], "10043":[5,6,7,8], "10025":[17,18,19,20]}

out_to_df = make_data_list(example_dt)
print(final_list)
```

This performs as expected and returns

```
[['10065', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['10043', 5, 6, 7, 8], ['10025', 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

However, when I try it with a larger dictionary, I get a strange, unacceptable result.  So with this larger (more values in value list) dictionary:

```
dummy_large_dict = ({'1000000067':[9929, 33, 54, 125, 414, 766, 852, 612, 625, 844, 633, 749, 710, 769, 611, 635, 632,
                             919, 881, 653, 871, 658, 555, 646, 751, 662, 533, 637, 486, 688, 449, 562, 306, 513,
                             618, 281, 418, 428, 388, 477, 553, 549, 377, 421, 298, 486, 347, 378, 487, 376, 468,
                             460, 374, 566, 421, 469, 518, 403, 580, 474, 506, 404, 541, 421, 383, 481, 431, 504,
                             579, 693, 507, 443, 614, 570, 479, 610, 651, 496, 692, 617, 600, 694, 821, 758, 464,
                             1082, 749, 517, 639, 720, 545, 908, 852, 746, 703, 694, 861, 851, 771, 732, 762, 881,
                             672, 663, 927, 979, 903, 612, 618, 552, 699, 623, 687, 667, 647, 704, 622, 840, 811,
                             589, 719, 599, 665, 611, 524, 755, 695, 524, 510, 440, 651, 462, 429, 716, 666, 596,
                             493, 496, 480, 469, 351, 442, 378, 472, 448, 348, 441, 491, 382, 476, 381, 322, 549,
                             440, 483, 427, 383, 647, 336, 398, 571, 654, 531, 449, 609, 584, 578, 514, 516, 657,
                             481, 608, 785, 673, 724, 791, 524, 740, 783, 630, 719, 774, 587, 811, 683, 749, 802,
                             704, 936, 750, 868, 513, 796, 776, 784, 836, 771, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               '1000000154':[99929, 33, 54, 125, 414, 766, 852, 612, 625, 844, 633, 749, 710, 769, 611, 635, 632,
                             919, 881, 653, 871, 658, 555, 646, 751, 662, 533, 637, 486, 688, 449, 562, 306, 513,
                             618, 281, 418, 428, 388, 477, 553, 549, 377, 421, 298, 486, 347, 378, 487, 376, 468,
                             460, 374, 566, 421, 469, 518, 403, 580, 474, 506, 404, 541, 421, 383, 481, 431, 504,
                             579, 693, 507, 443, 614, 570, 479, 610, 651, 496, 692, 617, 600, 694, 821, 758, 464,
                             1082, 749, 517, 639, 720, 545, 908, 852, 746, 703, 694, 861, 851, 771, 732, 762, 881,
                             672, 663, 927, 979, 903, 612, 618, 552, 699, 623, 687, 667, 647, 704, 622, 840, 811,
                             589, 719, 599, 665, 611, 524, 755, 695, 524, 510, 440, 651, 462, 429, 716, 666, 596,
                             493, 496, 480, 469, 351, 442, 378, 472, 448, 348, 441, 491, 382, 476, 381, 322, 549,
                             440, 483, 427, 383, 647, 336, 398, 571, 654, 531, 449, 609, 584, 578, 1514, 2516, 3657,
                             841, 678, 785, 673, 624, 991, 524, 740, 873, 630, 719, 1774, 1587, 1811, 1683, 1749, 802,
                             704, 976, 1750, 3868, 513, 796, 776, 784, 836, 771, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

out_to_df = make_data_list(dummy_large_dict)
print(out_to_df)
```

I get this result, which I don't understand at all.

```
[['1', '0'], ['1', '0']]
```

Comment: Why all this _dance_ just to concat two elements? `[[k] + v for k, v in example_dt.items()]` should be more than enough.

Comment: Could you check your posted example function? There are a few issues, but as posted, you shouldn't be seeing positive results at all. If, for example, you fix the unindented `return final_list`, you should still only be seeing something like `[['1', '0'], ['1', '0']]` for any list(dict). With `tr[0]` and `tr[1]`, you're simply slicing the first and second digits from `tr`, which are `1` and `0` in your examples.

Comment: `input_list = list(dict_in)` This will only give a list of keys. Not key-value pairs. I'm getting `[['1', '0'], ['1', '0'], ['1', '0']]` with your "correctly-working" example code.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply iterate over dictionary using `dictionary.items()`

your code may look like this

```
final_list = []

for key, value in dict_in.items():
   key_list = [key] + value
   final_list.apend(key_list)

return final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
final_list = [k]+v for k,v in example_dt.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion in your code between list and dict operations.

While the comments mention other ways of approaching this, if you wish to take this approach, or understand a little of why it isn't working, here's a rewrite retaining the `dict()` structure that should serve to illustrate what's going wrong in your original code. Though, as written, I don't see how the smaller dict could return anything other than what the large one is returning in the your posted code. Perhaps you made changes without realizing it before trying the larger dict?:

```
def make_data_list(dict_in):
    # convert dict to list
    # input_list = list(dict_in)
    input_list = dict_in
    final_list = []
    for tr in input_list.keys():
        data_list = [tr]
        for value in input_list[tr]:
            data_list.append(value)
        final_list.append(data_list)

    return final_list


example_dt = {"10065":[1,2,3,4], "10043":[5,6,7,8], "10025":[17,18,19,20]}

out_to_df = make_data_list(example_dt)
print(out_to_df)
```

In your original code, you're simply slicing the first and second digits from what you wish to be the key in a dict, but that has been converted to a list.

Also, as posted, your code should simply fail, because the `return` is unindented.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_data_list(dict_in):
    # convert dict to list
    input_list = list(dict_in)
```

This makes `input_list` a list of the *keys* of dict_in (it's unnecessary, as you can do a for loop over the dict directly, but others covered that already).

```
final_list = []
for tr in input_list:
    data_list = [tr[0]]
```

So here `tr` is one of the keys, and `tr[0]` is *the first character* of the key.

```
for v in tr[1]:
```

And `tr[1]` is the second character, and this loop only loops over a single character.

```
         data_list.append(v)
final_list.append(data_list)
```

So that's why your list ends up as `[['1', '0'], ['1', '0']]`. No idea what version of the code did work with your other example, but this one doesn't.